# Is there a way to find the current terminal colours in a script?

Tags: ruby, shell, colors, terminal

I have a set of ruby scripts that uses the Rainbow gem for setting coloured output.

The main issue that I have come across is the colours don't necessarily look good depending on what style of Terminal the user has set up (for example, I use a light background, and the colours look great on mine, however one of the coloured output are completely unreadable on a dark grey background).

One idea I had was to detect if the current terminal is a light/dark setup, and have a configuration for each one.

Has anyone come across this issue before, and if so - how did they work around it?

Comment: Either use basic colors (green = success, red = error) or provide a color configuration file (a "theme") the user can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from a simple Google search https://www.google.com/search?q=detect+terminal+background+colors , this is a pretty impossible feat for Ruby, much less something more core like Bash. There are many different terminal possibilities (KDE, Gnome, XTerm, Putty, etc), and they all track the background in different ways, making this goal all the harder.

Probably the best solution is to have an environmental variable that the user can set to flip between the light and dark color configuration, and include it in the help documentation you write.